# In Django Framework, i want to send a mail for forgot password from host to the user

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

In settings.py: here is the mail code:-

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'login'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('benipalmanpreet1207@gmail.com')
Email_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('gfyuirununkbxplp')
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

EmailBackend.py:- it is use for sending mail.

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
class EmailBackEnd(ModelBackend):
def authenticate(self,  username=None, password=None, \*\*kwargs):
UserModel = get_user_model()
try:
user = UserModel.objects.get(email=username)
except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
return None
else:
if user.check_password(password):
return user
return None
```

let me know if anything wrong in this code. I want to send mail for the forgot password from host_user to the website user who want to try forgot password.